# Performance wise, is it faster to use 'nullptr' or just '0'?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, c++11

For example:

```
object* pObject = nullptr;
```

OR:

```
object* pObject = 0;
```

Again, which one is better performance wise?

Comment: They are exactly the same. Look at the assembly output.

Comment: See http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nullptr` is of type `std::nullptr_t` and so the constructor be overloaded. This means the fact that it is null is encoded in the type, so it can be theoretically faster by avoiding a conditional.

Pointers obviously don't have overloaded constructors so whether you use `0` or `nullptr` is irrelevant. Same machine code, same performance.

Anyway, go with `nullptr` when you want a null pointer. Be careful of `0` as it will call integer overloads rather than pointers.

Comment: -1 for claiming that using the null literal `0` is somehow less type safe.

Comment: Yes, that's much better.  But you still shouldn't talk about "integers".  It's the literal `0`, and nothing else, that's being discussed.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Surely the literal `0` has the type `int`?

Answer (score 2):

They're exactly the same. The fact that the literal `0` can be used to initialize a pointer is purely a part of the language syntax and processed by the compiler; the result is identical to using `nullptr` to initialize a pointer: You get a null pointer.

`nullptr` is part of the type system and has nothing to do with the generated machine code. (It exists so that there is a literal with pointer type, which didn't use to exist.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to std::string.

I'm also assuming you meant to type `string* mystr = 0;`. If it's not a pointer, it can't be null.

They almost certainly compile to exactly the same thing, use whatever you like.

---

With the edit to be `object*`, my answer is the same. The two will almost certainly compile to the same thing, so use whatever you like.