# Why does using `nullptr` cause a performance hit [on LeetCode]?

Tags: c++, performance, nullptr

As part of LeetCode, I wrote a simple recursive function to traverse a binary tree and output all the possible paths. (It's not necessary to think about this to answer my question. I'm just providing sample code in order to demonstrate a concrete example.)

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> binaryTreePaths(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<string> paths;
        if( root != nullptr ) {
            string str;
            binaryTreePathsHelper(root, paths, str);
        }
        return paths;
    }

    void binaryTreePathsHelper(TreeNode* node, vector<string>& paths, string str) {

        str += std::to_string(node->val);

        if( node->left  == nullptr &&
            node->right == nullptr ) {
            paths.push_back(str);
        } else {
            str += "->";
        }

        if( node->left != nullptr ) {
            binaryTreePathsHelper(node->left, paths, str);
        }

        if( node->right != nullptr ) {
            binaryTreePathsHelper(node->right, paths, str);
        }
    }
};
```

LeetCode was saying my solution was rather slow, compared to other submissions:

[image]

After a good deal of experimentation, the biggest improvement to my code seemed to be replacing all

```
foo != nullptr
```

with simply

```
foo
```

*e.g.*

```
    void binaryTreePathsHelper(TreeNode* node, vector<string>& paths, string str) {

        str += std::to_string(node->val);

        if( !node->left && !node->right ) {
            paths.push_back(str);
        } else {
            str += "->";
        }

        if( node->left ) {
            binaryTreePathsHelper(node->left, paths, str);
        }

        if( node->right ) {
            binaryTreePathsHelper(node->right, paths, str);
        }
    }
```

which instantly brings me to the top:

[image]

According to the answers at [Performance wise, is it faster to use 'nullptr' or just '0'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205885/performance-wise-is-it-faster-to-use-nullptr-or-just-0), it seems it shouldn't make (this much of) a difference. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tested your code in another environment? Possibly it's just a LeetCode's feature.

Comment: `nullptr` checks are optimized away by compilers. So I guess there isn't any big deal in it.

Comment: Benchmark your code yourself to get verifiable results. I don't see a reason to rely on somebody who uses unknown methids and tools.

Comment: You cannot trust runtimes on competitive programming websites. The same code when run twice can have two different runtimes.

Comment: I have edited the title to include "on LeetCode" so as not to mislead future visitors and Google searchers about the performance of `nullptr`.

Comment: And the answer is still that "the compiler should treat `if (ptr)` and `if (ptr != nullptr)` as well as `if (!ptr)` and `if (ptr == nullptr)` - and their `if (ptr != 0)` and `if(ptr == 0)` counterparts - exactly the same. This is a very simple "optimisation", and I'd be very surprised if ANY compiler doesn't cope with this.

Comment: Since using `nullptr` is a good practice and there should be no difference in performance (as other users confirmed here, even with the compiler version LeetCode says they use), I would recommend contacting LeetCode and bringing this issue to their attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that `main.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct TreeNode {
 int val;
 TreeNode *left;
 TreeNode *right;
 TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> binaryTreePaths(TreeNode* root);
    void binaryTreePathsHelper(TreeNode* node, vector<string>& paths, string str);
};

vector<string> Solution::binaryTreePaths(TreeNode* root) {
       vector<string> paths;
       if( root != nullptr ) {
          string str;
          binaryTreePathsHelper(root, paths, str);
       }
       return paths;
    }


 void Solution::binaryTreePathsHelper(TreeNode* node, vector<string>& paths, string str) {

       str += std::to_string(node->val);

       if( node->left  == nullptr &&
           node->right == nullptr ) {
           paths.push_back(str);
       } else {
           str += "->";
       }

       if( node->left != nullptr ) {
            binaryTreePathsHelper(node->left, paths, str);
       }

       if( node->right != nullptr ) {
            binaryTreePathsHelper(node->right, paths, str);
       }
};
```

While `main2.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct TreeNode {
 int val;
 TreeNode *left;
 TreeNode *right;
 TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> binaryTreePaths(TreeNode* root);
    void binaryTreePathsHelper(TreeNode* node, vector<string>& paths, string str);
};

vector<string> Solution::binaryTreePaths(TreeNode* root) {
       vector<string> paths;
       if( root ) {
          string str;
          binaryTreePathsHelper(root, paths, str);
       }
       return paths;
    }


void Solution::binaryTreePathsHelper(TreeNode* node, vector<string>& paths, string str) {

       str += std::to_string(node->val);

       if( !(node->left) &&
           !(node->right) ) {
           paths.push_back(str);
       } else {
           str += "->";
       }

       if( node->left ) {
           binaryTreePathsHelper(node->left, paths, str);
       }

       if( node->right ) {
           binaryTreePathsHelper(node->right, paths, str);
       }
};
```

Let's generate asm code and compare results:

```
$ gcc -S main.cpp -o main.S -std=c++11
$ gcc -S main2.cpp -o main2.S -std=c++11
$ diff main.S main2.S
1c1
<       .file   "main.cpp"
---
>       .file   "main2.cpp"
```

There is no change in generated asm code (even with `-O3`). So no, there is no performance hit possible. At least not with the use of `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609` and `clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)`.

Comment: I see, so perhaps Leetcode uses something else behind the scenes. Thank you.

Comment: Any ideas as to what general thing a compiler might do that would cause `nullptr` comparisons to take longer? I know it's a shot in the dark, but just curious.

Comment: I expect this to be the outcome from any gcc and clang compiler, and I doubt that Microsoft compilers, Intel compilers, or even the 20 year old Turbo C++ would treat the two forms differently.

Comment: Maybe `nullptr` is just an address to `0`. It could cause cache miss and would require to use instruction that compare two values not one value with zero. But it is hard to me to believe that any compiler could do so.

Comment: I have found from https://leetcode.com/faq/ that the compiler is g++ 6.3. I'm going to accept this answer, because compilers / optimizations are out of my depth, and I don't know if a better answer would ever come up.

Comment: I've checked also `g++ 6.3.0`(I have used https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/4b5e15daff8b54440e3fda451c318ad31e532fab). Behavior is the same.